# Loss in validation with Pytorch result NaN or a high loss

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a deep learning and when I put someone value, or show "Perda NaN" (Loss NaN) or Loss in validation so high. Learning hate to be 0.08 and momentum is 0.

```
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import os
import random
import shutil

# Defina as sementes para reproducibilidade
torch.manual_seed(123)

# Diretórios dos dados
data_dir_train = 'train'
data_dir_test = 'test'

# Transformações para treinamento e teste
transform_train = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.Resize([64, 64]),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ]
)

transform_test = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.Resize([64, 64]),
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ]
)

# Carregamento dos dados
train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir_train, transform=transform_train)
test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir_test, transform=transform_test)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)

# Classe do modelo
class classificador(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, (3, 3))
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.bnorm = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=64)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2))
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(in_features=14 * 14 * 64, out_features=256)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.output = nn.Linear(128, 15)

    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.pool(self.bnorm(self.activation(self.conv1(X))))
        X = self.pool(self.bnorm(self.activation(self.conv2(X))))
        X = self.flatten(X)
        X = self.activation(self.linear1(X))
        X = self.activation(self.linear2(X))

        # Saída
        X = self.output(X)

        return X

# Instancie o modelo
net = classificador()

# Função de perda e otimizador
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.08, momentum=0.)

# Dispositivo para treinamento
device = torch.device('cpu')
device

net.to(device)

# Função de treinamento com as alterações necessárias
def training_loop(loader, epoch, model, optimizer, criterion, clip_value):
    running_loss = 0.
    running_accuracy = 0.

    model.train()  # Certifique-se de que o modelo está em modo de treinamento

    for i, data in enumerate(loader):
        inputs, labels = data
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(inputs)
        ps = F.softmax(outputs, dim=1)
        top_p, top_class = ps.topk(k=1, dim=1)
        equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
        accuracy = torch.mean(equals.type(torch.float))
        running_accuracy += accuracy

        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()

        # Clip de gradientes
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), clip_value)

        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        print('\rÉpoca {:3d} - Loop {:3d} de {:3d}: perda {:03.2f} - precisão {:03.2f}'.format(epoch + 1, i + 1, len(loader), loss, accuracy), end='\r')

    # Imprimindo os dados referentes a essa época
    print('\rÉPOCA {:3d} FINALIZADA: perda {:.5f} - precisão {:.5f}'.format(epoch + 1, running_loss / len(loader), running_accuracy / len(loader)))

# Número de épocas
epochs = 20
clip_value = 1.0  # Define o valor de clip dos gradientes

for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Treino
    print("Treinando")
    training_loop(train_loader, epoch, net, optimizer, criterion, clip_value)
    net.eval()
    # Teste
    print("Validando")
    training_loop(test_loader, epoch, net, optimizer, criterion, clip_value)
    net.train()

# Salvar o modelo treinado
net.eval()
torch.save(net.state_dict(), "checkpoint.pth")
```

Return

```
Treinando
ÉPOCA   1 FINALIZADA: perda 2.52318 - precisão 0.184744
Validando
ÉPOCA   1 FINALIZADA: perda 2.49540 - precisão 0.186060
Treinando
ÉPOCA   2 FINALIZADA: perda 2.42010 - precisão 0.203160
Validando
ÉPOCA   2 FINALIZADA: perda 2.39942 - precisão 0.220670
Treinando
ÉPOCA   3 FINALIZADA: perda 2.37517 - precisão 0.211457
Validando
ÉPOCA   3 FINALIZADA: perda 2.31256 - precisão 0.243990
Treinando
ÉPOCA   4 FINALIZADA: perda 2.33311 - precisão 0.234393
Validando
ÉPOCA   4 FINALIZADA: perda 2.28414 - precisão 0.244950
```

I need try to change my code or I should try to use "Keras"?

Answer (score 2):

Try initializing the weight and bias as shown in the code below.

If the variance of the weight or bias matrix is too large, the loss will increase.

[This paper](https://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf)(Xavier initialization), and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852)(He initialization) will help you understand why this is so.

```
class classificador(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.features, self.classifiers = [], []

        self.features += [nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 3), nn.ReLU(inplace=True), nn.BatchNorm2d(64), nn.MaxPool2d(2)]
        self.features += [nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3), nn.ReLU(inplace=True), nn.BatchNorm2d(64), nn.MaxPool2d(2)]
     
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()

        self.classifiers += [nn.Linear(14 * 64 * 64, 256), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
        self.classifiers += [nn.Linear(256, 128), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
        self.classifiers += [nn.Linear(128, 15)]

    for m in self.features:
         if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
             nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode="fan_out", nonlinearity="relu")
             if m.bias is not None:
                 nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
    
    for m in self.classifier:
        if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
            nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0, 0.01)
            nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
    
    self.features = nn.Sequential(*self.features)
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(*self.classifiers)

    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.features(X)
        X = self.flatten(X)
        X = self.classifiers(X)
        return X
```

Answer (score 0):

8e-2 is a pretty high learning rate. Try 1e-5, work your way up if that's stable.